# JavaScript variable assignment

Tags: javascript, variables, object, variable-assignment

Maybe the question already exists, but I don't find anything because I don't know how to call this problem.

I have an object function and want to assign the object variable into a variable:

```
this.myFunction = function() {
    var selection;                // internal variable
    selection = this.selection;   // both are [0,0]

    console.log(this.selection);  // result: [0,0]

    selection[0] = 500;           // set internal variable[0] 500
    console.log(selection);       // result: [500,0]
    console.log(this.selection);  // result: [500,0] <-- expected: [0,0]
}
```

How I can change the local variable without changing the other?

Comment: You need to create a copy of the array.

Comment: javascript assignment is always by reference for objects, if you want also the reason why

Comment: `Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations.` This means whenever you assign an array to another variable, it's just a mutator. It's not a deep clone.

Comment: @Kaddath: that's a common misunderstanding and not what *by reference* means. JavaScript is *pass by value*, but the value is *a* reference (to an object).

Comment: In JS, Objects (and arrays are objects) are passed by _reference_ -- as such, selection and this.selection _refer to the same array_.  If you want them to be different you'll have to do as other commenters have suggested and make a copy of the array ([array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) should be a good option to do that).

Comment: @anied: please see my previous comment.

Comment: Not directly related to your question/problem, but what do you think `this` in `this.myFunction` means? What do you think `this` in `this.selection` means?

Comment: @SterlingArcher What do you mean by "mutator"?

Comment: good precisions Sterling Archer and Felix Kling, thx

Comment: @FelixKling - sure, fair point, this is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference#13104500).  I was simply using a common shorthand to help illustrate the point.

Comment: @torazaburo it means that anything done to the array reflects on all references -- aka mutative. All native array methods mutate the array, they do not create clones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `selection = this.selection`, you are copying the reference of `this.selection` value. So when you change the local variable `selection`, you are changing `this.selection` too.

You have to use the method [`slice()` to create a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) from the value. Like this:

```
selection = this.selection.slice();
```

Comment: `selection = this.selection.slice()` works thanks